# Facing Vulnerability on prisma-client-lib-1.34.12

Tags: prisma, prisma-graphql

I am facing a vulnerability on using  prisma-client-lib-1.34.12. I have a violation code
**CVE-2023-26136** Can anyone help?

I am using the Mend tool for scanning and finding vulnerabilities